# Content not visible native-base

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I have simple anatomy with header, content and footer inside container, But only header is visible and nothing visible in content (with header and content only)

```
<Header>....</Header>
<Content><Text>Some content</Text></Content>
```

But, if I place all ie. header, content and footer. Then footer replaces header and only footer is visible.
Content is not at all visible in any case. native-base -v 2.3.1

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce this anytime there is a parent component in the hierarchy that does not have `flex: 1` that Noah Allen listed in his answer. Be sure to look up the entire component hierarchy to ensure there are no `<View>`'s being used as un-styled wrappers.

The easiest way to reproduce this error is to wrap all the content in an unstyled `<View>` component:

```
<View>
  <Container>
    <Header />
    <Content>
      <Text>
        This text does not show when Container is wrapped in a "View"
      </Text>
    </Content>
  </Container>
</View>
```

See a demonstration here:
https://snack.expo.io/@asametrical/native-base-content-empty

Removing the `<View>` component makes the text render inside `<Content>`. Applying `flex: 1` as a style as Noah mentioned to ALL parent `<View>` components in the hierarchy also ensures the content is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap everything in a View, with a style set like so:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Header>...</Header>
  <Content>
    <Text>Some content</Text>
  </Content>
  <Footer>...</Footer>
</View>
```

And then in your stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, // You should only need this
    height: '100%', // But these wouldn't hurt.
    width: '100%'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try upgrading to latest version of native-base(current version is 2.6.1)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>Header</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Content>
          <Text>
            This is Content Section
          </Text>
        </Content>
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button full>
              <Text>Footer</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried with latest initially, But with latest version i was not able to see any thing. So i switched to 2.3.1

Comment: @pram if you have not applied any styles the above code should work. Try setting 'marginTop:100' to Text. Also try adding more components to the content component.

Comment: Content tag is not at all showing up. if i add header,content and footer, i see only footer on top